# Fast algorithm for reduction modulo a prime

Tags: algorithm-design, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

If the prime is $p=2^a\cdot3^b+1$ , is there any fast reduction technique modulo this prime?

Comment: This isn't really related to cryptography and might be better suited for [math.se].

Comment: @ArtjomB. This is math that's directly relevant to the design of cryptographic algorithms, and it's about an algorithm which makes it more computer science than math, so I really can't see this question being off-topic here.

Comment: How big are $a$ and $b$? How big is $|a-b|$? How does the larger algorithm you want to use this in look like?